# Persisting entities using a REST API

Tags: php, api, rest, orm, persistence

For a project in Symfony2 I need to be able to persist / retrieve entities using an external RESTful API, instead of the database. Since Doctrine maps the entity to a row of a database table, I thought it should be easy to create a mapping from the entity to an external API as well. However, this is new for me and I can't seem to find any descriptions / tutorials about this. (perhaps I'm missing the right words for my Google-fu)

I was hoping there is a solution similar to Doctrine. I'd rather not use something based on the ActiveRecord pattern, because I want the persistance logic to be seperated from the Entities. The Entity shouldn't know how it is persisted.

I want to be able to do something similar to this:

```
$entity = new Entity();

$em = $this->getREST()->getManager(); // get REST Entity Manager
$em->persist($entity); // save the entity using a POST request
$em->flush();
```

and this:

```
$em = $this->getREST()->getManager(); // get REST Entity Manager

// retrieve the entity using a GET request
$entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Entity')->find($id);
```

and this:

```
$em = $this->getREST()->getManager(); // get REST Entity Manager

// retrieve all entities using a GET request
$entities = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Entity')->findAll();
```

In other words, it would be nice if the syntax could be almost identical to Doctrine's.

Furthermore, I'd like to configure the mapping in an external file (YAML for instance) instead of by annotations in the entity. (As I said, the entities shouldn't know how they are persisted)

[Forgottenbas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20382774/1001110) has already mentioned a couple solutions, but they don't completely satisfy my requirements, and I'd expect there would be more solutions, as I'm sure I'm not the first one who has to tackle this problem.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About one year ago I am trying to find the answer to same question with no luck and create own bundle. Unfortunately, I can not share it, because it's proprietary and not intended to be open-source (low amount of settings, made ​​specifically for our corporate API etc). But I can give you some links

1. At start there is a [jms serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) for deserializtion + [buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz) for http queries. You can wrap it with some service and works done.
2. Doctrine has some lost solution called [drest](https://github.com/doctrine/rest)(doctrine rest).
3. Also i found some interesting solution also called [drest](https://github.com/leedavis81/drest). I dont try to use it, since it is relatively newly. [Documentation](http://leedavis81.github.io/drest/) looks pretty well.

Comment: Thanks. Both drest solutions seem to be going in the right direction. However, I want to keep persistance seperated from the entities, just like using Doctrine itself. Doctrine's drest uses the Active Record pattern, so it's too tightly coupled. The second drest seems like a better option, but I hope there are other configuration options instead of annotations.

Comment: @Nic This should be accepted as answer. Everything you mentioned in your Q can be achieved with the jms serializer. You can wrap your customizations into a service to make it accessible like the entity manager.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how. Can I somehow extend Doctrine2, in order to keep the same syntax, but at the same time simply replace the DB logic with REST logic?

Comment: Never mind. I've created a seperate question about extending Doctrine: [Save entities to a REST API instead of DB using Doctrine 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555763/save-entities-to-a-rest-api-instead-of-db-using-doctrine-2). If no other answers are posted before the bounty period is over, I'll award it to forgottenbas.

Comment: @Nic I dont think that its a good idea to combine doctrine EM with rest-related stuff. One thing is save and load entities - its pretty easy, but what about DQL, relations? Also different API have different interface and abilities and your realization can be very API specific

Comment: @forgottenbas I think it should be possible... we obviously can't use DQL but we can use a (custom) EntityRepository that provides basic `find()`, `findAll()`, etc. methods. I'm trying to keep it as general and reusable as possible of course. But if I'm missing something, be sure to let me know! (preferably in [the Doctrine-specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555763/save-entities-to-a-rest-api-instead-of-db-using-doctrine-2))

Answer (score 4):

Well Circle has built a complete REST driver for Doctrine which means you can use EXACTLY the same syntax because it IS Doctrine acting as REST client:

https://github.com/CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for a doctrine dbal driver for rest apis i think

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while on the search for the same functionality. However, some time has passed again and it seems now that there is [a solution implementing this](https://github.com/rapl/rapl).

From the documentation:

> RAPL (RESTful API Persistence Layer) is a RESTful variant of Doctrine's ORM. It implements the same interfaces, but allows you to store and retrieve entities from a remote (RESTful) API instead of from the database.

Comment: Funny that you mention it ;) that's a library I created myself after this SO question didn't result in a proper solution. Unfortunately, it is not feature complete yet as I haven't had much time to work on it.

Comment: lol, indeed! :) Going in circles here too... your library looks exactly like what I'm looking for - giving the EntityManager control over populating the models seems architecturally sound. It is certainly better than giving control over data sources and persistence to the controller - which is something I have found numerously on other websites. However, I'm puzzled about why this doesn't find more traction... I wonder why not more people want to do this. Maybe it is a very specific use case? I don't know.

Comment: I guess in most cases it makes more sense to use a client library maintained by the owner of the API. However RAPL should make it easy to connect with an API that doesn't ship with a PHP client library, even though it requires a bit more work to set up compared to Doctrine ORM (because APIs are not as standardised as SQL databases).

Comment: I agree - plus most other people would consume the REST API in their front end, e.g. via AngularJS. Would just be the guys who have internal REST APIs using the RAPL approach - which is typically for a multi-tier architecture and quite corporate.

Comment: @Nic: I have posted some questions on the issue register on your GitHub project. I would appreciate if you could have a look to help me get started. Thanks, heaps.

Comment: how to install and configure RAPL? does anyone have an example?